# Select multiples elements in a list using xpath in Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

Below is the HTML structure.
I want to store all value in to a hashmap.
I will loop through rows and columns.
When looping through column i will identify the element present in the column and handle it differently.
Will this work : findElements(By.xpath("label | input | select")

```html
<tr>
<td><label>hdash</label> </td>
<td> <input type='text'/></td>
<td><input type='select'/></td>
.
.
.
</tr>
```

---

List RatesRows= ratesTbl.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
for all rows{

List RatesColumns= RatesRows.get(i).findElements(By.tagName("td"));
  for all columns{
       List RatesdataColumn = RatesColumns.get(j).findElements(By.xpath("label | input | select"));
}

}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfe9I.png)

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Will this work : findElements(By.xpath("label | input | select"))

Comment: Why don't you try and see?

Comment: I tried it doesn't work. If you see the RatesColumns list it holds one <td> tag, the tag can contain an input or label or dropdown , I need a xpath which will work in this scenario

Comment: You need to explain what *it doesn't work* means. You get an exception? unexpected results? something else?. You should also post the html as text and not as image. Post the error message and stack trace (if there are any) as well.

Comment: I need to write xpath for the above code snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to pass the xpath in that way. Instead you can get the child elements from td

```
RatesdataColumn = RatesColumns.get(j).findElements(By.xpath(".//*");
```

then you can use the element as per your use case

if your HTML is in this way

```
<tr>
<td><label>hdash</label> </td>
<td> <input type='text'/></td>
<td><input type='select'/></td>
.
.
.
</tr>
```

In the first iteration you will get `<label>hdash</label>` from `RatesdataColumn = RatesColumns.get(j).findElements(By.xpath(".//*");`

if you want to store the data in Hashmap just use getText method

```
for(WebElement childElement : RatesdataColumn){
    hashMap.put("<<Key Value>>", childElement.getText());
}
```

Comment: yeah :) , it worked this xpath ".//*" is pure gold , i was trying to solve it for 3 days. thanks man , Appreciate